# Mollom in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

How can I use Mollom Gem with a Rails 3 application?

I have installed the gem via: **sudo gem install 'mollom'**

I have the following entry in the Gemfile:  **gem 'mollom'**

In the controller I have wrote: **require 'mollom'**

But this line in the controller is giving the following error: "no such file to load -- mollom"

If I delete that line from the controller, then I have this error: 
uninitialized constant PostController::Mollom when trying to use Mollom.new...

Any ideas how to fix it would be great. I already have the keys from Mollom and everything works well on irb.

Thank you.

Best regards,
Tony.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the solution. I was too stupid to add the require '...' in the controller. 
Instead, add: 

require 'rubygems' and 

require 'mollom'

 in the application.rb file.

In the documentation here: http://mollom.rubyforge.org/ there is a mistake, at least when I used it with Rails 3. You need to replace: m.check_captcha with m.valid_captcha?

Comment: Here is a detailed example: 
http://georgetony.com/web-programming/ruby-on-rails/using-mollom-with-rails-3/